# Why my USB flash drive become 2.0 from 3.1 and how to fix it?

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive, usb-storage, usb-3, usb-2

I bought USB flash drive last month, I'm sure it is USB 3.1.
It was so fast that time.

This few days I notice it becomes so slow. 6GB data now takes 20-minutes during the transfer. And now when I tried to eject it, It says on label that it is USB 2.0.

I don't know how is that possible, when I bought this device from the label I am sure that it is USB 3.1.

Can anybody explain why it becomes USB 2.0? How can I make it USB 3.1 again?

All of my system’s USB ports are USB 3.1. I tried some of my other USB flash drives which are USB 3.1 too and they're all normal, except this one.

> USB BRAND: Transcend, 16GB
>
> OS: Windows 10

Comment: Please edit your question: You need to provide more details. Such as what OS you are using and what is the brand, model number and capacity of the USB flash drive.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.